# USB Modem software works fine on Windows 7 but gives a BSOD in Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, bsod, modem

Yesterday I inserted my USB modem and started the Modem software and boom! A BSOD appeared showing KMODE EXCEPTION NOT HANDELED (mtkmbim7 x64.sys). After that my PC rebooted normally but now whenever I start the software with modem inserted it gives me same error (but not in win 7). I even uninstalled the software and reinstalled it but the BSOD isn't fixed. It was working fine before yesterday but I don't know how this happened. I also tried "SFC/scannow" but nothing happened. Please help me!

```
Modem Specs:- MMX 377G 3G USB MODEM
```

Comment: Sounds like the driver for the device does not support Windows 10. Yes; USB devices can or cannot specific operating systems.  I would verify there isn't a new version of the software available.

Comment: @Ramhound But it worked fine until now for nearly 2 years on Windows 10. BTW I also tried running it in compatibility mode for windows 7 but no good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've solved the same problem, just install with XP SP2 compatibility the usb 3G setup!
I have solved today with a digicom 3.5G key